# Remove margin paragraphs from the paper

Tags: geometry, book-design, marginpar

I have a document that includes no margin paragraphs (`\marginpar{..}`), and therefore there is no need to give any area on the paper for the `marginparsep` and `marginparwidth` lengths.

To achieve that, what I can do is just set the above lengths to zero with `geometry`. But is that considered a good practice?

It would make the desired visual effect of getting more area for the main text, but I wonder if that is the correct way.

Comment: As you were told earlier margin pars are not related to the layout. So a zero with `\marginparwidth` does not do anything relevant when one does not use margin pars. If you instead ask whether it is good practise to set right or left margin to zero, then yes I think that would be a bad idea.

Comment: if you remove the margins on A4 or US Letter paper then use a 10pt font on the full width, then the lines will be far too long for reading. The margins are large not primarilay for margin paragraphs, but because A4 paper is wide and the text width for single column text can't be made much wider if it is to be read.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I am familiar with the "do not exceed 70 characters in a line" recommendation. I want to prepare a title page layout and a back matter layout (when printing bibliographies and indexes and acknowledgments etc) for my book. In those parts of the document, no marginal paragraphs are necessary, and this is the reason I am asking.

Comment: @tush a title page is far from being "the main text" so I don't think anyone would understand the question that way. In any case you can lay out a title page ignoring the document margins if you want so it doesn't much matter if you set them to 0 or not. As I say the use or not of marginal notes had almost no bearing on the choice of default text width so in general there is no reason to change the text width because there are no marginal notes. Most documents do not have marginal notes.

Comment: You are right. I should edit the original question. The thing is that I want the content of those parts to be centered. With marginals you do not assure that.